# how to properly use the copy constructor and assignment in c++ class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have written copy constructor for the pointer data member for one of my class

```
class person
{
public:

 string name;
int number;
};



  class MyClass {
     int x;
    char c;
    std::string s;
    person student;
    MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& other ) :
    x( other.x ), c( other.c ), s( other.s ),student(other.student){}
 };
```

but I am getting the following error when I run this program

error: extra qualification ‘MyClass::’ on member ‘MyClass’ [-fpermissive]
am I properly using the copy constructor .

Comment: As the error message says, `MyClass::` is unnecessary.

Comment: (But only because you're defining the constructor inline in the class' body.)

Comment: You don't seem to have a pointer data member in either of the classes you've shown. Your copy ctor does member-wise copying. The one the compiler would generate does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& other )
^^^^^^^^^^
```

The fully qualified name is necessary only when you define the body outside the class definition. It tells the compiler that this particular function(*which happens to be the constructor in your case*) belongs to the name qualified class.
When you define the body within the class definition it is implied that the function is an member of the class in which you are defining it so fully qualified name is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class person
{
public:

string name;
int number;
};

 class MyClass {
 int x;
 char c;
 std::string s;
 person *student;
 MyClass(const MyClass& other);
};

MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& other ) :
 x( other.x ), c( other.c ), s( other.s ),student(other.student){
  x = other.x;
  c = other.c;
  s = other.s;
  student = other.student;
 }
```

It compiles fine now  . still I have one doubt that , am I properly doing the an explicit copy constructor and assignment operations.?

Comment: No for `student` because it is a pointer and you are assigning it to the copy's `student`. Unless that is the behavior you want (i.e. all MyClass instances point to the same copy of `student`), you need to write a person constructor that handles copying of its members.

Comment: Also, you don't need to re-assign the members again in the constructor body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want shallow copy, (all `MyClass` instances point to the same copy of `student`), do this:

```
MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& other ) :
    x( other.x ), c( other.c ), s( other.s ), student( other.student ) {}
```

Otherwise, you want deep copy, which is implemented this way (note the de-reference):

```
MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& other ) :
    x( other.x ), c( other.c ), s( other.s ) {
    student = new person(*(other.student)); // de-reference is required
}
```

Run the following code to see the difference:

```
MyClass a;
person mike;
mike.name = "Mike Ross";
mike.number = 26;
a.student = &mike;
MyClass b(a);
b.student->number = 52;
cout << a.student->number << endl;
cout << b.student->number << endl;
```

Shallow copy output:

```
52
52
```

Deep copy output:

```
26
52
```